# Listview as a detail fragment in master/detail view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

Am creating a master/detail fragment from [this](http://android-devtut.blogspot.in/2012/07/fragments.html) link. This works fine, now here instead of textview in detail fragment class i would like to implement listviews, (ie) i would like to display the details of the masterview as a child listview, hence i tried 
detail.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView 
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            />"
 <ListView 
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listview2"
            />"

    </LinearLayout>
```

and in my detailFragment class

```
public class DetailFragment1 extends ListFragment {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      String[] values = new String[] { "1", "2", "3",
                "4"  };
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
              setListAdapter(adapter);

     }
```

My problem is child listview is displaying at initial stage but i want to display this listview when i click the first row of master page.Am new to fragments, so help me in achieving this. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing like this, you can design a layout which contains ListView as master and frameLayout container. In frameLayout container, you can dynamically inflate layout, which is designed in such a way that you can have child listview and details view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".NavigationActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/strip_background"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/nav_lv_transactions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_fl_frag_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In onclick listerner put this code,

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putString(ARG_ITEM_ID,
"Some Name");
MyClassFragment newFragment = new MyClassFragment();
newFragment.setArguments(arguments);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.nav_fl_frag_container, newFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Try this. It will work

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.. How can i implement the layout  in my onclick listener class

Comment: Create a fragment for the layout that you wants to inflate(with child), and then in on click listener put the code i have edited.

Answer (score 1):

Create a CallBack interface:

```
public interface Callbacks {

        public void onItemSelected(long id);
}
```

Let the fragment inplement it:

```
public class DetailFragment1 extends ListFragment implements CallBacks {
```

In the ListFragment OnListitemClick:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {     
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(id);
}
```

In the Activity:

```
Public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Callbacks {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(long id) {
    // Replace the detail fragment with the corresponding item selected in the list
}
```